# Socket.io 1.0.5 : How to save session variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Unfortunately socket.io developer team decided to deprecate functions set() and get(). The problem is that these two functions allowed us to save variable into session.

So my question is : What is the equivalent of the folloing code on socket.io 1.0.5 ?

```
socket.set('mySessionVar', 'myValue');

socket.get('mySessionVar', function (error, mySessionVar) {
    console.log('I have a super variable save in the session : '+mySessionVar);
    socket.emit('mySessionVar', mySessionVar);
});
```

Thank you for your help,
Guillaume.

Answer (score 7):

[socket.io-handshake](https://github.com/fullstackers/socket.io-handshake) is session middleware for socket.io 1.x.  It is built on top of express-session and cookie-parser.  I know we are talking about socket.io and not express, but it still works with socket.io.  This example will make your sessions live on a redis store.

```
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var connectRedis = require('connect-redis')(expressSession);
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var config = { session: { secret:'secret', key: 'bus.io', store: new connectRedis() } };
var handshake = require('socket.io-handshake');
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
io.use(handshake(config.session));
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.handshake.session.data = "whatever data I want";
  socket.handshake.session.save();
});
```

Comment: please, can you add to your `socket.io-handshake` github/npm that one can access session variables in this way ... `socket.handshake.session.data`. It is difficult to find out otherwise.

Comment: I published a new version

Comment: I'd like to set your answer as valid, but I lost this old account. I'll upvote you instead. Sorry :/

Answer (score 6):

Your 'socket' is a Javascript object, to which you can add any additional key/values.

```
socket['mySessionVar'] = 'myValue';
console.log( "I have a super variable save in the session: " + socket['mySessionVar']);
```